# my responsive site does not respond when I make the screen bigger

Tags: html, css

I want to make my website responsive but it's not responding to the min-height changes I want. I want it to change colors when it reachers a breakingpoint so can someone analyze my CSS and html and see wha's wrong.

Thanks,

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {background: navy; }
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 660px;) {
 body { 
     background:  darkgreen;}
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Dalexis Peguero | Designer </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,800italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet' href="responsive.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html" id="logo">
        <h1>Dalexis Peguero</h1>
        <h2>Designer</h2>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html" >About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <h3>General Information</h3>
        <p>I am not currently looking for new design work, but I am available when I feel confident with my skills. </p>
        <p>Please reach me with email or facebook when it's not an emergency, but if you need an urgent consultation just call me.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3> Contact Details </h3>
        <ul class="contact-info">
          <li class="phone"><a href="tel:555-5555">555-5555</a></li>
          <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:dalexispeguero@gmail.com">dalexispeguero@gmail.com</a></li>
          <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=nickrp">@Dpeguero</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/nickrp"><img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="twitter logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/dalexisp"><img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="facebook logo" class="social-icon"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Dalexis Peguero. </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not very responsive then... ;)

Comment: You should also remove the semi-colon from your `660px` rule.

Answer (score 2):

this might be your problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet' href="responsive.css">
```

you are **not** closing properly the quote in **`rel`**, so change to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
```

with this not be properly closed, it will **not** load the `resposive.css` file

Plus you have a incorrect semicolon here:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 660px;)
```

remove it, should be like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 660px)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little typo in your media query, simply remove `;`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {background: navy; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {
body {background:  darkgreen;}
}
```

Moreover, I would add an exclusive media query :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
body {background: navy; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {background:  darkgreen;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First up, let's just really simplify things:

> How can I change my background colour responsively based on the window width

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jua13epq/**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background: lime;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background: navy;
    }
}
```

Your rules contradicted each other a little before.

Note how my example uses `min-width` and `max-width` to make the conditions mutually exclusive to one and other.

Comment: Also there is a syntax error in the OP's media rule for 660px